# Redundant repetitive documentation links in PhpStorm quick-documentation when adding them manually

Tags: javascript, documentation, phpstorm, jquery

I'm using Php Storm 2016.2.1. To access the *quick documentation* for the jQuery API inside the IDE, I've got the [`jquery.d.ts`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts) from GitHub. When I introduce the file to the IDE through the form at `File / Settings / Languages & Frameworks / JavaScript / Libraries`, everything is almost fine, except that by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> I'm presented with a popup menu containing two identical hyperlinks pointing to a same content, which is redundant and really annoying.

[image]

As you see in the picture above, the *External Documentation (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)* is totally disabled! why?

What I've missed or how may I resolve these issues?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

`wrapInner()` is overloaded in jquery.d.ts; and quick documentation represents each overload as a separate link. It's a bug, please follow [WEB-24428](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24428) for updates